# Bull : Missing process handler for the job

Tags: typescript, cron, scheduled-tasks, nestjs

I am trying to process `repeatableJobs` in a queue at an interval, specified in the cron string of that job, all the jobs have a unique name (generated by uuid). I keep on adding jobs as per my requirement so basically all the jobs in the queue must be processed according to the `repeatOptions` for that job

**Controller**

```
@Controller('jobs')
export class WeatherController {
    constructor(
        @InjectQueue('mainQueue') readonly queue: Queue,
        private httpService: HttpService,
    ) {}

    @Post('report')
    async scheduleReport(@Body() scheduleData) {

        const cronString = scheduleData.cron;

        const repeatOptions = { cron: cronString };
        const jobName = uuid();

        const job = await this.queue.add(jobName, scheduleDataId, {
            repeat: repeatOptions,
            attempts: 3,
        });

        return job.id;
    }

}
```

**Job Consumer:**

```
@Processor('mainQueue')
export class MainConsumer {
    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

    @Process()
    async report(job: Job) {
        try {
            console.log('Job is being processed');
            //Do some process
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }


    //When a job fails
    @OnQueueEvent('failed')
    onFailed(job: Job) {
        console.log(`The job with name ${job.name} failed`);
    }
}
```

But in every 5 minutes, the jobs get failed with `"Error: Missing process handler for job type 5edf63855e613810d2e44820\n`

Is there a way to process the jobs without passing `jobName` to the `@Process()` decorator? Because the jobs are not fixed and neither their names.

Comment: You'd need to provide a processor for every *named job*. So I don't think it's possible. Why do you need the `jobName` to be unique?

Comment: I don't need the name to be unique, I just want to be able to remove/update the jobs on user request